# List comprehension in list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
allChannelTraffic = [ { "Web" : 4, "android" : 3 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 },]
```

I would like to know the **easiest way to get an output like this from the above list:**

```
[{'Web':7,'android':3}]
```

Where I want to get the sum of the values of all the keys. I heard that using list comprehension in python, we can easily do operations. Can someone please tell me how to implement this using list comprehension?

Comment: @DavidG Not really, since the android key does not occur in every dict

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
from collections import Counter

allChannelTraffic = [{"Web": 4, "android": 3}, {"Web": 1}, {"Web": 1}, {"Web": 1}, ]

result = sum(map(Counter, allChannelTraffic), Counter())

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'Web': 7, 'android': 3})
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are not really useful here.

Generator expressions instead allows us to do the following:

```
allChannelTraffic = [ { "Web" : 4, "android" : 3 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 },]
keys = set(k for d in allChannelTraffic for k in d.keys())
totals = {key: sum(d.get(key, 0) for d in allChannelTraffic) for key in keys}
print(totals)

# {'Web': 7, 'android': 3}
```

That last one `{key: sum([...]) for key in keys}` is a dictionary comprehension by the way.

And I could have used a set comprehension instead of the `set()` in line 2:

`{k ... for k in d.keys()}` == `set(k ... for k in d.keys())`

But I'd rather not do that, since the `set()` is much clearer for the reader.

In general though the Counter or Defaultdict approach for your problem might be more understandable for unexperienced pythonistas....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to sum up the values for each key

```
import collections
totals = collections.defaultdict(int)
for sub in allChannelTraffic:
    for key, value in sub.items():
        totals[key] += value
```

Output

```
>>> totals
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'android': 3, 'Web': 7})
```

Comment: Nice answer, but just cuz he wanted a list comprehension, here it'd be: `[totals[key] += value for key, value in sub.items() for sub in allChannelTraffic]`

Not to steal your thunder, I just like one liners :)

Comment: @Jaba that would not work as the key would not exist and it would throw an error

Comment: It's a defaultdict though. I may be wrong..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a list comprehension, but you can always use [`Counter.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) here:

```
from collections import Counter

allChannelTraffic = [ { "Web" : 4, "android" : 3 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 }]

counts = Counter()
for d in allChannelTraffic:
    counts.update(d)

print(counts)
# Counter({'Web': 7, 'android': 3})
```

A non-library approach would look something like this:

```
allChannelTraffic = [ { "Web" : 4, "android" : 3 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 }]

counts = {}
for d in allChannelTraffic:
    for k in d:
        counts[k] = counts.get(k, 0) + d[k]

print(counts)
# Counter({'Web': 7, 'android': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allChannelTraffic = [ { "Web" :4,"android" : 3 }, { "Web" : 1 }, { "Web" : 1 },{ "Web" : 1 },] 
allChannelTraffic = [{"web": sum([item[1].get("Web",0) for item in enumerate(allChannelTraffic)]), "android":sum([item[1].get("android",0) for item in enumerate(allChannelTraffic)])}]
```